Difficulty Maintaining Form Data Structure Across Postbacks in ASP.NET WebForms
I am facing an issue. I am creating a form that contains multiple fields, some related to tables. When I submit the form, I need to insert the primary data into the master table and additional data into the children table. The children table may have multiple rows. I implemented this using JavaScript, but when I fill the data in multiple rows and for some reason, like a text change in the form, there's a postback, the multiple rows become one field separated by commas! How can I handle this to keep them in multiple rows? Also, how can I display the multiple rows when I need to update all of them in the ASP.NET WebForms project?
js to add or remove rows
function duplicate(event, rowId, fieldOne) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var originalRow = document.getElementById(rowId);
    var clone = originalRow.cloneNode(true);
    clone.removeAttribute('id');
    clone.querySelector('#' + fieldOne).Text = '';

    originalRow.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}


function deleteRow(event, button) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var row = $(button).closest('tr');
    if (row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow2' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow3' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow4' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow5' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow6' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow7' && row.attr('id') !== 'originalRow8' ) {
        row.remove();
    } else {
        alert('Cannot delete the original row.');
    }

webforms example of the rows


نقل المشروع






                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                         <th class="text-center">
                            ملاحظة
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            تاريخ 
                        </th>
                       
                        <th class="text-center">
                            الإجراء
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="originalRow3">
                          <td class="text-center">
                            1
                        </td>
                       
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="projDesc" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            
                            
                        </td>
                     
                         <td class="text-center">
                          
  <asp:TextBox ID="decisionDate" runat="server" class="form-control datepicker" style="text-align:right;"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                          <td class="text-center">
    <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="+" 
        CssClass="btn btn-md plus-color m-1" 
        ValidationGroup="PE" OnClientClick="duplicate(event,'originalRow3','projDesc')" />
        
         <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="-" 
        CssClass="btn btn-md minus-color m-1"
        ValidationGroup="PE" OnClientClick="deleteRow(event,this)" />
</td>
                        
                      
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
            <asp:Label ID="errorMessage3" runat="server" Visible="False" ForeColor="Red" style="text-align:right;"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    
    
    
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
  <asp:GridView ID="TransferProjectSpecGridView" CssClass="table table-bordered" 
              runat="server" 
              AllowSorting="True" HorizontalAlign="Center">
  
                    </asp:GridView>
                    
                    
</div>
    </div>
    
</div>

[enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/zOsY0wh5.png)
